# The inradius in a right angled triangle with integer side is r, if r = 4 the greatest perimeter is ??

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

The inradius in a right angled triangle with integer side is $r$,  if $r = 4$ the greatest perimeter is ??

My attempt- I know that $ r = (s-a)\tan \frac{A}{2}  $

Thus $ 2r = a+b-c $

I also know that $ a \le  b \lt c $

I also tried squaring both the sides and using Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that makes this problem actually have a solution (rather than allowing the perimeter to go to infinity) is that the triangle must have **integer sides.**

Since the shorter leg of the triangle must be greater than $8$ and less than 
$8 + \sqrt{32} < 14$ (you can figure out why, if you like), there are only a few possible lengths the shorter leg can have. 
So one approach to the solution is, you could simply try each one.

If you think about what would make the perimeter greater or less without the integer-side restriction, you might have a clue which side length to try first and when to stop looking, which would save some effort.

Another possible approach is to use the formula for generating Pythagorean triples:
$c = m(p^2+q+2),$ $a = m(p^2 - q^2),$ $b = 2mpq.$
This will also get the answer, though it might still involve some trial and error.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by 8 + $ \sqrt 2 \lt 14 $ ???

Comment: The maximum "shortest leg" occurs when the triangle is isosceles. The exact value actually doesn't matter much; the point is, the short leg can't be very long and there are only a few integer lengths to check if you just try each one. Eventually you will find as you keep trying new lengths that the "short" leg is now longer than the "long" leg, and at that point you can know there can be no other possible triangles you haven't already tried.

Comment: @David K I used an observation you made on another post to edit my answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

We begin with Euclid's formula for generating Pythagorean triples.
$$A=m^2-n^2 \qquad B=2mn \qquad C=m^2+n^2$$

The inradius of *this* triple is
$\quad r=\dfrac{A+B-C}{2}=(m-n)n=4\quad$ so we need
$\,(m-n=4\land n=1)\, \text{ or } \,(m-n=1\land n=4).\quad$

For $\,\big((5-1)1\big),\, F(5,1)=(24,10,26).\,$ The triple is not primitive and the perimeter is $\,60.$

For $\,\big((5-4)4\big),\, F(5,4)=(9,40,41).\,$ The triple is primitive and the perimeter is $\,90.$